# How can I replace all words in a string except one

Tags: c++

So, I would like to change all words in a string except one, that stays in the middle.

```cpp
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>

int main()
{
    string test = "You want to join player group";
    string find = "You want to join group";
    string replace = "This is a test about group";

    boost::replace_all(test, find, replace);

    cout << test << endl;
}
```

The output was expected to be:

```
This is a test about player group
```

But it doesn't work, the output is:

```
You want to join player group
```

The problem is on finding out the words, since they are a unique string.
There's a function that reads all words, no matter their position and just change what I want?

**EDIT2:**
This is the best example of what I want to happen:

```cpp
    char* a  = "This is MYYYYYYYYY line in the void Translate"; // This is the main line
    char* b = "This is line in the void Translate"; // This is what needs to be find in the main line
    char* c = "Testing - is line twatawtn thdwae voiwd Transwlate"; // This needs to replace ALL the words in the char* b, perserving the MYYYYYYYYY

    // The output is expected to be:
    Testing - is MYYYYYYYY is line twatawtn thdwae voiwd Transwlate
```

Comment: Where is you attempt? Look like hackerrank task ;) . Split by ' ' empty string for ++ by char. Then simple find mid (word sum / 2 ). On the end check left and right size() if you have odd like sum.

Comment: Did you also intend to change `master` to `leader`?

Comment: Yes, sorry once again for my bad explanation, the edit was updated

Comment: Do you know in advance where the word you want to keep will be in the `replace` (or `c`) string?

Comment: No, the word is not to be replaced, but what you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invert your thinking here. Instead of matching "All words but one", you need to try to match that one word so you can extract it and insert it elsewhere.

We can do this with [Regular Expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), which became standardized in C++11:

```
std::string test = "You want to join player group";
static const std::regex find{R"(You want to join (\S+) group)"};
std::smatch search_result;
if (!std::regex_search(test, search_result, find))
{
    std::cerr << "Could not match the string\n";
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    std::string found_group_name = search_result[1];
    auto replace = boost::format("This is a test about %1% group") % found_group_name;
    std::cout << replace;
}
```

#### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BRgMwC7z1CDAYyef)

To match the word "player" I used a pretty simply regular expression `(\S+)` which means "match one or more non-whitespace characters (greedily) and put that into a group"

"Groups" in regular expressions are enclosed by parentheses. The 0th group is always the entire match, and since we only have one set of parentheses, your word is therefore in group 1, hence the resulting access of the match result at `search_result[1]`.

To create the regular expression, you'll notice I used the perhaps-unfamiliar string literal syntax`R"(...)"`. This is called a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) and was also standardized in C++11. It was basically made for describing regular expressions without needing to escape backslashes. If you've used Python, it's the same as `r'...'`. If you've used C#, it's the same as `@"..."`

I threw in some [`boost::format`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) to print the result because you were using Boost in the question and I thought you'd like to have some fun with it :-)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted!
But I have a small question, how can I put a string (eg: test) inside of ```std::regex find``` with that expression ```(\S+)```?

Comment: @Nathan: Are you asking how to do [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qBU4zISnylKHt05z)?

Comment: No, probably is better with a real exemple. I have a program that cout this (eg): ```"The player %s is now master", "AndyG""```and output this: ```The player AndyG is now master``` so what I want to preserve is your name, transforming the string to ```The player AndyG is now leader```

Comment: @Nathan: I think I'm beginning to understand. Forgive me if I'm still a little off. It seems like the usage of `boost::format` is what you want. `boost::format("The player %1% is now master") % "AndyG"`

Comment: No need to apologize, you're helping a lot, thanks for the time!
Yes but what I want was something like this:
```
std::string test = "You want to join player group";
static const std::regex find{R"(\S+)" + test };
```
but just calling the player out, nothing else

Comment: @Nathan: I think that my answer does call `player` out? It's captured in `search_result[1]`. I think you're now asking how you can modify the input string to replace the discovered word? Like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PSUI1ngxDR4gyN9k)?

Comment: No my friend, it's the opposite.
I edited the main topic again, 
I hope I have been enlightening now

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `find` is not a substring of `test`, so `boost::replace_all(test, find, replace);` has no effect.

Removing `group` from `find` and `replace` solves it:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string test = "You want to join player group";
  std::string find = "You want to join";
  std::string replace = "This is a test about";

  boost::replace_all(test, find, replace);

  std::cout << test << std::endl;
}
```

Output: `This is a test about player group`.

In this case, there is just one replace of the beginning of the string because the end of the string is already the right one. You could have another call of `replace_all` to change the end if needed.

Some other options:

- one is in the other answer.
- split the strings into a vector (or array) of words, then insert the desired word (player) at the right spot of the replace vector, then build your output string from it.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to take out the word group, it needs to be there.

Comment: @Nathan It needs to be where? If in the output, it is.

Comment: This is just an exemple of a big program that works with like this: ```"The player %s is the master now!", "Keldorn"``` and I want to translate it to other languages and I can't do that in the way you're saying

Comment: This answer does what is asked in the question. If they are other constrains, please add them to the question.

Comment: Done, sorry for the trouble